# Cоставить функцию перевода из 10-ой системы счисления в 12-ую

Tags: c++, функции, системы-счисления

Нужно перевести из 7ой в 10ую, а потом в 12ую. На последнем шаге я и споткнулся
Некоторые функции нужно было писать самому (strlen, atoi, itoa)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int size(string str)         //strlen
{
int i = 0;
while (str[i] != '\0')
{
    i++;
}
return i;
}

int atoi(char s)   //atoi
{
return s - '0';
}

char itoa(int a)  //itoa
{
return a + '0';
} 

int translater(string str, int x)  //перевод из 7ой в 10ую
{
for (int i = 0; i < size(str); i++)
{
    x += atoi(str[i]) * pow(7, size(str) - 1 - i);
}

return x;
}

int trans2(string str, int x)
{
//Здесь нужна функция перевода из 10ой в 12ую
}



int main()
{
string str1;
int x=0;
cout << "Enter your number in sevenfold number system:\n";
cin >> str1;
cout << "Your number in sevenfold number system:\n" << str1 << endl;
cout << "Your number in decimal system:\n" << translater(str1, x) << endl;
cout << "Your number in duodecimal system:\n" << trans2(str1, x);



return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю, что ваша функцию `translater` должна или через ссылку вернуть число в 10-ой системе счисления, или результат `return` куда нибудь сохранить. Я добавил ссылку для параметра `x`.

Перевод из 10 в какую либо другую систему счисления, происходит следующим образом:

1. Получаете остаток от деления исходного числа на 12 (в вашем случае)
2. Если остаток `>= 10`, то начиная с 10 вы вставляете буквы латинского алфавита по порядку. То есть `10 = a`, `11 = b` и т.д. (В вашем случае остаток может получиться `10` или `11`. Далее символ вставляете или в начало результирующей строки или в конец (Но нужно будет её инвертировать под конец)
3. Далее делите число на 12 (в вашем случае)
4. Повторяете операции пока число > 0

Попробуйте сначала сами реализовать алгоритм описанный выше :)

А так вот пример функции:

```
string trans2(int x)
{
    string result;
    do {
        char s = '0' + x % 12;
        if (s == 58) s = 'a';
        if (s == 59) s = 'b';
        result = s + result;
        x /= 12;
    } while (x > 0);
    return result;
}
```